# How to perform a POST request using background task for React Native apps using expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, background, expo

I am trying to log my GPS coordinates in a React-Native expo application.

The background task **runs successfully** and consoles log the coordinates.

Now I want to send them to my server.

For example a `post request to /api/mylocation?lon=123&lat=345`

I tried a regular fetch method but I get a timeout error.

*regular meaning fetch(url,{ method:'POST'  etc}) **(I know how to perform a basic fetch)***

How can I solve this? I suspect it has to do with `async` and all that.

```
  const LOCATION_TRACKING = 'location-tracking';

  const startLocationTracking = async () => {
    console.log('startLocationTracking');
    await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TRACKING, {
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,
      timeInterval: 10000,
      distanceInterval: 0,
    });
    const hasStarted = await Location.hasStartedLocationUpdatesAsync(
      LOCATION_TRACKING
    );
    console.log('tracking started?', hasStarted);
  };
  


  TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TRACKING, async ({ data, error }) => {
    console.log('running task:', data, error);
    // send_driver_location()

    if (error) {
      console.log('LOCATION_TRACKING task ERROR:', error);
      return;
    }
    if (data) {
      const { locations } = data;
      let lat = locations[0].coords.latitude;
      let long = locations[0].coords.longitude;
  
      console.log(
        `${new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString()}: ${lat},${long}`

      );



      // add a fetch method here? 

      // fetch(url, {...}


    }
  });
```

Obviously, this will be helpful when I want to fetch tokens from my server for authentication purposes also.